# Has anyone done saving and reloading state with QuickGrid?

Tags: .net, sorting, state, paging, quickgrid

Has anyone done saving and reloading state using the new QuickGrid component by Microsoft? I am trying to save the grid state to persistent data for a user, then when they go off to another page and come back to the page with the grid the same state of filtering, sorting paging, etc. is recalled.